# Loki release 404 not found problem

Tags: release-loki, updates

Whenever I hit `sudo apt update` I get this error message:

```
Err:6 http://archive.canonical.com loki Release    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com loki Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that particular repository is not needed for anything you can delete it from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` by right clicking on Files, selecting 'New Window as Administrator' then navigating to the folder previously mentioned.

Once you've done that, try `sudo apt update` and all should be fine. It would also be a good idea to apply any updates that are found by `sudo apt upgrade` or by using the App Center.

Again, this is only a solution in the event that this repository isn't needed.

Good Luck!!!

Comment: Can you specify more? which repository to delete?

Comment: You can use sudo privileges to open the above folder. Within that folder are a number of files, one of which is for the repository that is giving the 404 error. It should be named similar to the repository that is giving the error. Another way which may be simpler for you is to install Synaptic Package Manager (sudo apt install synaptic), open Synaptic, navigate to Settings, then Repositories. You can then delete the offending repository from the list.