# 404 NOT FOUND adding tweaks

Tags: release-hera, apt, tweak-tool

this is a similar issue to [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/20921/404-not-found-error-while-running-apt-and-appstore-eos-juno) question by me.  I just got a fresh install of EOS 5.1, so I am starting from scratch. I am trying to get Elementary Tweaks so I can install a custom theme, but when I try to add the repository I get this issue:

```
$  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
```

```
 system settings panel for elementary OS that lets you easily and safely customise your desktop's appearance  https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~philip.scott/+archive/ubuntu/elementary-tweaks
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Hit:1 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                 
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                              
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]                                                                            
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]                                                           
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                           
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]      
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                 
Get:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/elementary-tweaks/ubuntu bionic InRelease [15.9 kB]
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Get:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/elementary-tweaks/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages [820 B]
Get:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/elementary-tweaks/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages [828 B]
Get:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/elementary-tweaks/ubuntu bionic/main Translation-en [304 B]
Reading package lists... Done                        
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

It is giving similar error messages to the other question. Is this because there is not yet a tweaks version for EOS 5.1 Hera???
Any help is appreciated. I don't know if I should mention this on the Elementary Tweaks GitHub page or what. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I checked the README on the GitHub page, and it says it's for EOS Juno. I thought this would work because Hera is just an update to Juno, not an entirely new copy. Oh, well.

Comment: It should work for elementary OS Hera also - I use Hera and it is ok. Can you edit your question and put the lines that you typed into terminal in order to receive the log listed above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one:
`E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.`

Seems like a fairly old Elementary-tweaks ppa to me. It's erroring because it's not really up and running for Ubuntu Bionic.
Taking a quick look over the launchpad says it doesn't work for anything over eOS Freya(0.3), you should remove it with `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily` followed by `sudo apt update`

The other one you added works fine for me on Hera 5.1